# How do you use Add in Keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer, keras-2

In keras say you have

```
layer1
```

and

```
layer2
```

You want to add these two layers, and you have to use Add from keras.layers.merge and you can't use the functional api.

Add doesn't take any inputs, so I don't see how it can possibly help in setting up the graph. I'm using keras 2.06.

Comment: Why can't you use the functional API?

Comment: From Chollet's upcoming book: "These three important use cases --multi-input models, multi-output models, and graph-like models-- are not possible when using only the Sequential model class in Keras. But there is also a different, far more general and flexible way to use Keras: the functional API. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the sum of two layers like that, your network graph would look like this

```
   |        |
layer1    layer2
    \      /
     \    /
      \  /
       \/
      sum
```

Such a layer is *by definition* not sequential (since `sum` takes more than one input), so performing this using the Sequential API is impossible. You must use the Functional API.